# Efficient algorithm for computing the integral closure of a computable domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algorithms

what is known? even talking about efficiency relatively to the complexity of the computation of the domain itself?

Comment: I believe you should ask for help in forming a good question for this forum.  Ask a colleague to help you with the spelling as well as the content.  You might even ask for help on tea.mathoverflow.net.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.09

Comment: I believe you should ask for help in communicating with people. Maybe a colleague could assist?

Comment: @Lilach: Being snarky will get your question closed even faster.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, Igor.  Lilach, if facility with English is not an issue, perhaps there is some part of the "How To Ask" guide that is.  If you want help, I again recommend tea.mathoverflow.net.  Gerhard "My Apologies For Guessing Wrong" Paseman, 2012.10.12

Comment: @Igor: See if I care...

@Gerhard: 10x, but how did you get the impression that I am looking for such?  anyhow, you may fix my keyboard, if we are already talking ;-)

Comment: I for one don't see much wrong with the question as it is stated. I would say that in the case of domains finitely generated over a field, there is probably something that people familiar with computational algebraic geometry can offer. It is rather obvious to me, however, that the "complexity" of the integral closure (say, number of generators) may be much higher than that of the algebra itself.